# Does ag-grid charting support line interpolation options or stepped lines?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

A web app I am working on uses ag-grid to render detailed status data in a grid. Customer wants to chart a comparison between planned and actual status values, which I was able to do quickly and easily with ag-grid's charting capabilities. However, after a review the customer is interested in displaying the line as stepped between points rather than linear since each point is a target and data between targets is not interpolated in the details. I assumed that line interpolation was a fairly standard (and common) option for rendering line charts and would be supported. However, I cannot seem to find an option which allows me to set the line interpolation or stepping.

Am I just missing an option or is line interpolation and stepping just not supported for ag-grid line charts? If it is not supported, can this be done through some kind of customization, or am I stuck either adding points to my line to make it kind-of-sort-of look like a stepped line or pulling in a whole other charting library for what seems like a basic function?

Answer (score 1):

I came across the very same situation with stepped lines - I could not find any configurations for ag-charts which would result in this behavior. I ended up adding *fake* datapoints to the dataset to mimic the steps.
Only problem I have is that I should display the tooltip for the *real* datapoints whilst not for the *fake* ones. I almost got it working, no tooltip is rendered, but the tiny triangle that is right under the tooltip is still there on the canvas... Quite frustrating...

```
function chartThemeOverrides(): AgChartThemeOverrides {
  return {
    line: {
      series: {
        marker: {
          formatter: params => {
            return {
              // no marker for fake data points
              size: params.datum.fake ? 0 : params.size,
            }
          }
        },
        tooltip: {
          renderer: (params) => {
            return params.datum.fake ? {
              content: '',
              title: '',
            } : {
              content: `whatever you want as tooltip content`
            };
          },
        },
      },
    },
  }
}
```

[Fake datapoints chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLl9n.png)